# Rails Paypal Gem Find Payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm having trouble finding a payment after it has been executed. I just want to check if the payment was a success even though they are routed to a certain address if the payment was a success. When I put in binding.pry and check the params that are sent back after a successful payment I get these params:

```
{"token"=>"EC-5AG64573AN278762M",
 "PayerID"=>"SGH69NK5UUSFQ",
 "controller"=>"money",
 "action"=>"depositsuccess"}
```

According to here:
https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-ruby/blob/master/samples/payment/find.rb

I can just say Payment.find basically. Right now Im putting the token in the Payment.find so I have:

```
payment = Payment.find(params[:token])
```

Is that right? I get this error:

```
PayPal::SDK::Core::Exceptions::ResourceNotFound
```

Which I think means the payment was not found. Is this because Im in sandbox? I tried using a real payment example they gave and I got the same result. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
payment = Payment.find(params[:token])
```

Have you tried this:

```
payment = Payment.find(@payment.id)
```